# Python code returns: Syntaxerror non-keyword after keyword arg

Tags: python, scikit-learn, syntax-error

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = []
prices = []

def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        csvFileReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(csvFileReader)
        for row in csvFileReader:
            dates.append(int(row[0].split('-')[0]))
            prices.append(float(row[1]))
    return

def predict_price(dates, prices, x):
    dates = np.reshape(dates,(len(dates), 1))

    svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0,1)
    svr_lin = SVR(kernel='linear', C=1e3)
    svr_poly = SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree=2)
    svn_lin.fit(dates, prices)
    svr_poly.fit(dates, prices)
    svr_rbf.fit(dates, prices)


    plt.scatter(dates, prices, color = 'black', label = 'Data')
    plt.plot(dates, svr_rbf.predict(dates), color = 'red', label = 'RBF model')
    plt.plot(dates, svr_lin.predict(dates), color = 'green', label = 'linear model')
    plt.plot(dates, svr_poly.predict(dates), color = 'blue', label = 'polynomial model')
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.xlabel("Price")
    plt.title('Support Vector Regression')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    return svr_rbf.predict(x)[0], svr_lin.predict(x)[0], svr_poly.predict(x)[0]

get_data('aapl.csv')

predicted_price = predict_price(dates, prices, 29)

print (predicted_price)
```

OUTPUT:

```
 File "predictstocks.py", line 21
    svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0,1)
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Okay, so i have searched the internet for hours now, and looked in the different docs.. but i cant find the solution for my problem.
as my title says the python code returns this: Syntaxerror non-keyword after keyword arg

Comment: Please include the complete error as a quote in your question. What is the definition of `SVR`? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: When I type "Syntaxerror non-keyword after keyword arg" into the stackoverflow search box I get 77 questions. Have you read any of those to see if they explain what the error means, before asking this question?

Comment: needs `scikit-learn` tag? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html , `gamma : float`

Comment: Look carefully at `svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0,1)`. What is the `,1` at the end for? This is the "non-keyword" after the keyword arguments. Perhaps you meant `svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)`?

Comment: The error itself tells you what's wrong.  You have a non-keyword argument after keyword arguments in the method line you posted.  Keyword args are optional, non-keyword args (or just args) are not, and are __positional__.  As such, they must come first, then optional args come second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gamma=0,1` is two arguments, the first a keyword, the second positional, which is invalid. You probably want `gamma=0.1` instead.